# Which is the best way to mock an expression type?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, expression

I'm trying to test some of my code and in particular a method which receive in input an `Expression` object (the method extract the Name from the expression) that can be a Lamda or an Unary expression.

I tried to create the expression but it's really difficult to configure it as I need it. Also I don't understand how can I mock it up, cause the constructors is internal.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why do you want to mock this parameter? Expression type is a simple enough to use it as it is.

Comment: `Expression` is an abstract base class. You can use the static factory methods on it to create one programmatically or let the compiler generate one for you from a lambda expression: `Expression<Action> e = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello, world");`.

Comment: I'm having hard time understanding how to create the expression instance as I need it.
To be specific I need for example to create a Lambda Expression with the Body property of type MemberExpression o UnaryExpression. Also the Name property of the Body should have a value.